# Extracting data from nested tuples

Tags: python, data-structures, huffman-code

For an application I'm working on I need to create lists from nested tuples, representing the data contained in each branch.

For reference the tuples represent a Huffman tree, an example is:

```
tree = (1.0, (0.5, (0.25, (0.125, 'd'),(0.125, 'c')), (0.25, 'b')), (0.5,'a'))
```

This was created from a Huffman routine with the following probabilities:

```
a:0.5, b:0.25, c:0.125, d:0.125
```

I would like to out put a list which looks like

```
[['a'],['b','c','d']]
```

I've tried the following code:

```
def makeList(tree):
    if len(tree) == 2:
        return [tree[0]]
    else:
        rightlist = []
        leftlist = []
        right = list(tree[1])
        left = list(tree[2])
        for i in range(1, len(right)):
            rightlist.append(right[i])
        for i in range(1, len(left)):
            leftlist.append(left[i])
        return [rightlist, leftlist]
```

However this returns

```
[['a'],[(0.25, (0.125, 'd'),(0.125,'c')),(0.25,'b')]
```

Which isn't quite what I want.

How could I go about modifying my code above to produce the output I want?

**EDIT**

I have produced some code which given a balanced input:

```
('a',0.25), ('b', 0.25), ('c', 0.25), ('d',0.25)
```

produces the output I want:

```
[['a','b'], ['c','d']]

def makeList(tree):
if len(tree) == 2:
    print("I'm in here")
    return [tree[1]]
else:
    right = tree[1]
    left = tree[2]
    rightlist = []
    leftlist = []

    for i in range(0, len(right)):
        if type(right[i]) == tuple:
            print('right: ' + str(right[i]))
            rightlist.append(right[i][1])

    for i in range(0, len(left)):
        if type(left[i]) == tuple:
            print('left: ' + str(left[i]))
            leftlist.append(left[i][1])

    return [rightlist, leftlist]
```

However, it fails on the following inputs (output below):

```
exampleData = [(0.5, 'a'), (0.5,'b')]

[[],[[]]

exampleData = [(0.5, 'a'), (0.25,'b'), (0.25,'c')]

[[],['b'.'c']]

exampleData = [(0.5,'a'), (0.25,'b'), (0.125,'c'), (0.125,'d')]

[[]],['b',(0.125, 'd')]]
```

However, the gold-standard test that this needs to pass is creating these lists for random trees:

```
probs = np.random.dirichlet([1]*4).tolist()
indices = range(0,4)
exampleData = zip(probs, indices)
huffTree = makeHuffmanTree(exampleData)
groups = makeLists(groups)
```

Comment: Is this the actual code? I thought it was len not length and the for loop needed colons on the end

Comment: Could you explain how you determined that you want the output `[['a'],['b','c','d']]`? Why is `b` in the same list as `c` and `d`, when it has a different probability?

Comment: @doctorlove yes, of course. Have added the colons and removed the 1st length.

Comment: @Kevin I need to group the items according to how the Huffman routine creates the branches of the tree (i.e. it roughly splits the probability in half). So, ['a'] (which is on a  branch on it's own) and ['b','c','d'] should be returned from this routine. I *don't* want to return lists of symbols with the same probability.

Comment: I'm sensing recursion would be a helpful tool here.

Comment: I agree that `a` should be on a branch on its own. But shouldn't `b` _also_ get its own branch? The trees created by huffman coding are binary, so it doesn't make sense to me, to return a list with more than two elements. Are you sure you don't want something like `[a,[b,[c,d]]]`?

Comment: @Kevin I'm absolutely positive about what I want to do: that is two *flat* lists containing all the items from each branch. This is for a subroutine in an algorithm where I need to test the items in each branch for a property.

Comment: @ErikAllik How would I distinguish between the left and right branches recursively?

Comment: You seem to be re-defining the problem as you go along. Can you post your 'gold-standard' code somewhere as this example does not work, and it also makes no sense.

Comment: It turns out the problem was stripping the leaves of a (random) binary tree (that's what the new failing test creates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have the tree already, with up to two branches:

```
import Queue

def leaves(tree):
    result = []
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    queue.put(tree)
    while not queue.empty():
        node = queue.get()
        if type(node[1]) == tuple:
            for subnode in node[1:]:
                queue.put(subnode)
        else:
            result.append(node[1])
    return result

def makeList(tree):
    if len(tree) == 2:
        return [tree[1]]

    left = tree[1]
    right = tree[2]
    return [leaves(left), leaves(right)]
```

This takes the two branches and grabs the leaves of each one, discarding the first half of each leaf. It does it using a breadth-first search to avoid the recursion problem.

I couldn't convert the `exampleData` lists into trees in order to test them, but it works with the first problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have a recursive solution.

```
def makeListAndFlatten(tree):
    treeList = makeList(tree)
    branchA = treeList[0]
    branchB = treeList[1]
    flatA = flatten(branchA)
    flatB = flatten(branchB)
    return [flatA, flatB]

def makeList(tree):
    if len(tree) == 2:
        return tree[1]
    else:
        for i in range(1,len(tree)):
                return [tree[len(tree)-1][1], makeList(tree[i])]

def flatten(nestedList):
        def aux(listOrItem):
            if isinstance(listOrItem, list):
                for elem in listOrItem:
                    for item in aux(elem):
                        yield item
            else:
                yield listOrItem
        return list(aux(nestedList))
```

If we run:

```
makeListAndFlatten(tree)
```

This gives the result:

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
```

A list containing two lists with the leaves from the lower branches on both sides.

**EDIT:**

This code was based on the format given in the original question:

tree = (1.0, (0.5, (0.25, (0.125, 'd'),(0.125, 'c')), (0.25, 'b')), (0.5,'a'))

if the input format is changed then this will not work.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately the solution can't be recursive as I've got no control over the size of the tree (the number of symbols could be 1000's).

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to transform this into an iterative solution. As mentioned by @Kevin in the comments this appears to be a more sensible representation of the actual tree. You could always unpack the first and second elements in any way you like.

Comment: I would be interested in the relative performance of both solutions if you have some large data sets.

Comment: I don't want to appear rude, but I don't want what @Kevein suggested: I want the output I put in the original question. It's part of a subroutine which tests a property of the items on the leaves of the tree, and I'll need *everything* on a branch (in a nice list) to do that test.

Comment: I know what you wanted, and I actually made some suggestions in my comment to help you get there. I have edited my code, to illustrate this.

Comment: Thanks: I'll work out how to bounty this and give you the points.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again. Could you please explain how the makelist function works? It's not creating correct lists for even or random trees. I can't for the life of me figure out how to correct it.

Comment: The makelist function takes the labels from each leaf. Can you post code to generate the 'tree' input as the given code seems to reference libs without imports. You may be interested in looking at Amazon's Mechanical Turk for this kind of task as I am not sure it is appropriate just to get people on stack to do your work for you without any explanation or effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

seems like as a general algorithm, you would need a function which (1) calculates the total weight of the tree below and then (2) implement tree rotation to rotate the tree until you get it balanced. i.e. this is in some ways just a variation on a standard tree balancing algorithm, except that for an AVL tree for instance, you are balancing the depth, and here you are balancing the weight in the data itself.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean by the weight of the data?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the algorithm, but it sounds like each item has a probability which should add up to 1.0 (or a frequency, in which case the totals will be higher). in any case, ideally you want to end up with a tree with the root right in the middle, such that the left is approximately equal to the right (with the root added to one side or the other). that is what i mean by balanced. ie the tree would probably look like 'b' at the root, with 'a' on the left and 'c'/'d' on the right. do in-order traversal for each side to extract. add 'b' to 'cd' because (a-(b+cd)) < ((b+cd)-a)

Comment: As it turns out, you just had to strip the leaves using a breadth-first search.